# View.getHeight() returns 0 when using getViewTreeObserver()

Tags: android, height

I'm trying to get a textView height before draw it, so i use getViewTreeObserver code from other questions:

```
private TextView mTextView;
private int mTextViewHeight = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

mTextView = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.text);

mTextView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        mTextViewHeight = mTextView.getHeight(); // Tried with getMeasured() too

                        if (Utils.hasJellyBean()) {
                            mTextView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                    .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        } else {
                            mTextView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                    .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Using this code, i always get mTextViewHeight = 0. I've tried debuggin, and looking at entry point of OnGlobalLayoutListener, thread never access to "mTextViewHeight = mTextView.getHeight();" line.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The answer was great, but my error is that when i want to use mTextViewHeight in code, this code was been executed before entry on the Listener, so the value i was getting was the inital value. To fix that, i have to put inside the listener the code i want to use with the textView height.

BEFORE FIXED:

```
private TextView mTextView;
    private int mTextViewHeight = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    mTextView = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.text);

    mTextView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                        @Override
                        public void onGlobalLayout() {
                            mTextViewHeight = mTextView.getHeight(); // Tried with getMeasured() too

                            if (Utils.hasJellyBean()) {
                                mTextView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                        .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                            } else {
                                mTextView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                        .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                            }
                        }
                    });

    if(mTextViewHeight > maxHeightAllowed) {
        mTextViewHeight /= 2;
    } else {
        String text = new String("");
        for(int i = 0; i < mTextViewHeight.lenght(); i++)
        text = text + getNextWord[i];
    }
}
```

AFTER FIXING

```
private TextView mTextView;
private int mTextViewHeight = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

mTextView = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.text);

mTextView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        mTextViewHeight = mTextView.getHeight(); // Tried with getMeasured() too
                        if(mTextViewHeight > maxHeightAllowed) {
                            mTextViewHeight /= 2;
                        } else {
                            String text = new String("");
                            for(int i = 0; i < mTextViewHeight.lenght(); i++)
                            text = text + getNextWord[i];
                        }

                        if (Utils.hasJellyBean()) {
                            mTextView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                    .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        } else {
                            mTextView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                    .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `onPreDraw` function:

```
    ViewTreeObserver greenObserver = mTextViewHeight.getViewTreeObserver();
    greenObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            mTextViewHeight.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            System.out.println("The height is " + mTextViewHeight.getHeight());
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks!! Usefull Answer. I've edited my question posting my own answer i've found